# openswan installation

Tags: linux, ipsec, openswan

on a Linux machine with kernel 2.6.32, how to enable klips
i found that for enable klips mus enable

```
CONFIG_KLIPS_ALG=y
```

in kernel config.

but patch only available for 2.6.23- and for newer kernels, there is no patch. in kernel configs i cant find anything.

how can i enable that in 2.6.32, or there's other way to use klips?

i want to load custom crypto algoeithm and use by ipsec, is klips right way? or any other solution is for that?

excuse me for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

KLIPS was another IPsec Stack used a while ago.
Modern Linux-Kernels use NETKEY

There are many differences, the most obvious is that there isn't any ipsecX interface anymore.

If your documentation says something about KLIPS it's maybe outdated and will lead to more problems.